# Adding text to a plot with a specified color for each letter

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to add text to a plot, where each letter in the text has a specified color.

I know `addtable2plot` of the plotrix package allows adding a table (`data.frame` or `matrix`) to a plot, and allows the background colors of each cell to be specified. Unfortunately the same does not seem to apply for the text. So I was wondering if anyone has an idea how to achieve this.

For example:

```
plot(density(rnorm(1000,4,1)))
```

would be my plot

and then I would like to add this text:

```
c("T","T","A")
```

with these corresponding colors:

```
c("red","red","blue")
```

Comment: `text(x = c(2,4,6), y = .1, labels = c('T','T','A'), col = c('red','red','blue'))`

Comment: @rawr Post it as an answer.